# Use dbhelper class in adapter view but it has context that always show null and my method to delete the note is not working?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter

This is my database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "note_db" ;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Note.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public Long insertnote(String note){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Note.COL_NOTE,note);
        Long result = db.insert(Note.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();

        return result;

    }

    public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
        List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Note.TABLE_NAME ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Note note = new Note();
                note.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COL_ID)));
                note.setNote(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COL_NOTE)));

                notes.add(note);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // close db connection
        db.close();

        // return notes list
        return notes;
    }

    public int updateNote(Note note) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Note.COL_NOTE, note.getNote());

        // updating row
        return db.update(Note.TABLE_NAME, values, Note.COL_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteNote(Note note) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Note.TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + Note.COL_ID +" = " + note.getId() +"" );

        db.delete(Note.TABLE_NAME, Note.COL_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

this is my Main Activity

i have also make adapter in main activity
in the adapter i have used onlongclick listener.
im not much aware about it.
and when i click on alert dialog delete button it does nothing.
help me to get rid of this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rv;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton btnadd;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        notesList.addAll(db.getAllNotes());

        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        btnadd = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, notesList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addnote();

            }
        });

    }

    public void addnote() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_note,null);

        builder.setView(v);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();

        final EditText addnote = v.findViewById(R.id.edtnote);
        final Button addbtn = v.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        final Button cancel = v.findViewById(R.id.cancel);


        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (addnote.getText().toString().isEmpty()==false){

                    db.insertnote(addnote.getText().toString());

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Note Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please add note",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

       cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });


    }

    private void deleteNote(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteNote(notesList.get(position));

        // removing the note from the list
        notesList.remove(position);
    }

}
```

this is recycler adapter class
it is also placed in main activity

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    public List<Note> noteList;
//    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<Note> noteList){
        this.context = context;
        this.noteList = noteList;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView notes;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            notes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {

        final Context context = viewGroup.getContext();

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.show_note,viewGroup,false);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        final DatabaseHelper db  = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        holder.notes.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.update_delete_note, null);

                final Button update, delete;

                update = v.findViewById(R.id.update);
                delete = v.findViewById(R.id.delete);

                builder.setView(v);

                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

                update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                });
```

i get problem over here.
this code does nothing
and also i want to refresh the recyclerview in real time.

please show me how to do that too.

it is like i insert note and after that when i reopen app then it show note in recycler view .
i want to do that in realtime when i add it should suddenly show me added note.

```
                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.e(String.valueOf(context),noteList.get(i).toString());

                        Note note = noteList.get(i);
                        db.deleteNote(note);
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        });

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int i) {

        final Note note = noteList.get(i);
        holder.notes.setText(note.getNote());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your database is not in a proper format try to add an extension `.db` to your `DATABASE_NAME = "note_db.db" ;` So that maybe your database is not initialize well.  This link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java might be very helpful to you.

Comment: there is no issue with database name as i said insertdatabase() method works completely and also database i have checked is created so no problem with that i have a real problem in adapter class at db.deletenote(note)

Comment: OK, so did you already tried to declare first  the `setOnClickListener` to your `update` and `delete` button before showing the dialog?

Comment: yup only thing i want is that my adapter class should work with database and my deleteNote(which has Note) should get deleted when i long click on item

Comment: ohh sry long click on recyclerview item it shows alert dialog and then i have 2 buttons for that update and delete both of them not working

Answer (score 0):

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.e(String.valueOf(context),noteList.get(i).toString());

                        Note note = noteList.get(i);
                        db.deleteNote(note);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Add notifyDataSetChanged() and it will refresh the adapter because when you call that method than it tells the adapter that the data has been updated and the adapter will update with updated data.Also use this in your update note the same way.Just add this at last after you have finished your required operations.

I am posting the update answer with your code.
First add this method in your adapter

```
 public void refreshData(Context context,List<Note> noteList){
        this.context = context;
        this.noteList = noteList;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The reason is that when ever you insert new item in sqlite than you need to add that item to your list and send the updated list to adapter and in adapter you need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); and adapter will be refreshed.This is suggested way to refresh adapter.

next in Your activity addNote() method change it to:-

```
public void addnote() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_note,null);

        builder.setView(v);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();

        final EditText addnote = v.findViewById(R.id.edtnote);
        final Button addbtn = v.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        final Button cancel = v.findViewById(R.id.cancel);


        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etInterestName.getText().toString().trim())){

                    db.insertnote(addnote.getText().toString().trim());
                    notesList.add(addnote.getText().toString().trim());
                    adapter.refreshData(this, notesList);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Note Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please add note",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

       cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    }
```

First I changed `TextUtils.isEmpty(etInterestName.getText().toString().trim())` Since it a more better way of making sure a edit text is not null or empty and after you insert your item to sqlite simply add it to your list

```
 notesList.add(addnote.getText().toString().trim()); 
     adapter.refreshData(this, notesList);
```

And then call the refreshData method in your adapter and data will be updated.
Hope this solves your problem and if it does mark the ans as correct!!.

Comment: db.deleteNote(note);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: is not working there is nothing like notifyDatasetChanged(); at insertnote(), in maain activity

Comment: Okay  notifyDatasetChanged() does not belong to activity,So you cant access it from activity and if your talking about adapter than you can directly call that method and If you are talking about activity or fragment then you need to call it with the object of your adapter.In your case You need to call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() i.e adapter is your object which is referring to your adapter and in your activity and in adapter you can directly call it.Tell me if it is not working

Comment: i tried to do same as you told me still not refresh myrecview soon as i insert. i have to close app and then reopen then i got new note which i added,actually my more concern is for not deleting or updating my note !!!

Comment: Okay can you post your updated code ? After you have added what i told.

Comment: thank u for your time akhil i really admire that you are giving so much time in solving my problem but my query for now is bit different than your answer for now i am really concern about db.deletenote(note"noteobject") is not working!!

Comment: It doesn't matter if the query is different.But be sure to call adapter.refreshData method after you add the current inserted notes to the list.And If you want to use sqlite in a more easy way then i would suggest you to use Room which is relased recently by google which provides a abstraction layer above sqlite to use it more powerfully and in a ease of manner.If you need to know how to implement it than i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final Button update, delete;
update = v.findViewById(R.id.update);
delete = v.findViewById(R.id.delete);
builder.setView(v);
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("UPDATE BUTTON", "TESTING!!!");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("DELETE BUTTON", "TESTING!!!");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});


// Move this to bottom.
dialog.show();
```

This is what I mean, since the dialog is working and showing but those buttons are not working. Then monitor your log if it has an output or not.

Comment: thankyou for reply but my issue is not with alert dialog because my dialog presents when i long click on any notes, my question is that in adapter class i tried to call method of sqlite database with context as adapters context but database method deletenode(node) is not deleting!!

Comment: but thanks for effort in it i really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void deleteNote(int position) {
                dbHelper.deleteNote(noteList.get(position).getId());
                noteList.remove(position);
                Adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
```